# Find the sum of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{0.7^{n+1}}{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{0.7^{n+1}}{n+1}$ = ?
I have no idea how to solve it. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{0.7^{n+1}}{n+1} = 0.7(1+0.7(\frac{1}{2} + 0.7(\frac{1}{3} + 0.7(...))))$ or $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{0.7^{n+1}}{n+1} = 0.7(1+\frac{0.7}{2}(1 + \frac{0.7 * 2}{3}(1 + ...)))$

Comment: If you differentiate the series (thinking of $0.7$ as the $x$-variable), what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if we have $\vert x\vert<1$ we have that $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$. Since the convergence is uniform we can integrate interchanging sum with integral
$$F(x)=\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int x^n dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$
Also
$$F(x)=\int \frac{1}{1-x} dx=-\log (1-x)$$
So $$-\log (1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$
which implies that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{0.7^{n+1}}{n+1}=-\log (1-0.7)=-\log(0.3)=-\log 3+\log 10$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$
Let $x=0.7$